# Validating email, name phone etc in edittext field without clicking submit button in android

Tags: android, validation, email, android-edittext

I'm creating a registration form in android containing three edittexts. 1) Name 2)email 3) mobile number and finally there is a button for proceeding to next stage. Now when user inputs in name edittext, some value (such as characters or numbers), then proceeds to the next edittext email. Then I have to validate whether the name entered is valid or not. That is before starting to type in the email edittext, my app should display an error message such as invalid name in red color, below the name edittext. Also the name edittext should turn to an edittext with red color border in it. Similarly the edittexts email and mobile number has also to be validated like this. How can this feature be achieved in android?? I want to validate all edittexts before clicking the button to submit the data. Please help me..

Comment: use TextWatcher... and check google for samples..

Comment: use the focus change listener

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to validate when you enter text each and every time to acheive. You can go with `TextChangedListener`..

```
EditText NameTxt= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
NameTxt.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

    @Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        // doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
         // doSomething();
    }

    @Override
    public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

       // doSomething();



    } 

});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
@Override
    public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
       switch(arg0.getId()){
           case R.id.ditText1:
           editText1.setError("Enter a valid address");
           break;
           case R.id.editText2:
           editText1.setError("Enter a valid name");
           break;
           case R.id.editText3:
           editText1.setError("Enter a valid phNo");
           break;

       }
        Toast.makeText(this, "after text test", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

use `edittext_name.addTextChangedListener()`  like this way

```
       editText_name.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher(){

        @Override
        public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                int after) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
              // leave this blank

        }
        @Override
        public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before,
                int count) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        nameStr =edittext_name.getText().toString

        @Override
        public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            // check for validation here
            //  and set error if value is invalid
       if(your condition is invalid)
            txtView.setText("please enter correct name")




        }

    });
```

you can do this for email or any editText

Answer (score 0):

try this it may help you,

```
email.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.length() > 0){
                    if(!emailValidator(s)){
                        email.setError("Please Enter Valid Email!");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        phone.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {

            }

            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count,
                    int after) {
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {
                if(s.length() > 0){
                    if(!phoneValidator(s)){
                        phone.setError("Please Enter Valid number!");
                    }
                }
            }
        });

private boolean emailValidator(CharSequence email){
        Pattern pattern1 = Pattern.compile( "^([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+@([a-zA-Z0-9_.-])+\\.([a-zA-Z])+([a-zA-Z])+");

        Matcher matcher1 = pattern1.matcher(email);

        return matcher1.matches();
    }

    private boolean phoneValidator(CharSequence phone){
        if(phone.length() < 6 || phone.length() > 13)
            return false;
        else
            return true;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 @Override
 public void afterTextChanged(Editable arg0) {
   switch(arg0.getId()){
       case R.id.etEmail:
        if(isValidEmail(etEmail.getText().toString())){
         etEmail.setError("Enter valid Email ID"); 
         etEmail.requestFocus();} 
        break;

       case R.id.etPhone:
        if(isValidPhone(etPhone.getText().toString())){
         etPhone.setError("Enter valid phone number"); 
         etPhone.requestFocus();} 
       break;

       case R.id.etName:
       if(TextUtils.isEmpty(etName.getText().toString()){
             etName.setError("Enter a name");
       break;

   }
  }

public boolean isValidEmail(CharSequence target) {
  return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && android.util.Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(target).matches();}


public  boolean isValidPhone(CharSequence target) {
      return !TextUtils.isEmpty(target) && android.util.Patterns.PHONE.matcher(target).matches();}
```